# Error in unix shell scripting

Tags: unix, awk

I want to get the part of the filename by using AWK command. For,example my filename will be like ABC_20100702001500.CSV. I want to get YYYYMMDD format from my filename to create a directory. I tried with

```
name=$(awk -F"." '{print $f}' | awk -F"_" '{print $NF}').
```

But its shows error like syntax error near unexpected token `name=awk'. How could I resolve the problem. Please correct me with  correct syntax.

Comment: What is `$f`? A shell variable? That can't work inside single quotes. Where is the input to the first awk command? Also, there is no syntax error in the part you have shown us. What are the adjacent lines?

Comment: Any chance you are using some old shell that does not understand command substitution with `$(cmd)`? Then use backticks.

Comment: Run `shellcheck` on your code and if you still have a problem afterwards then post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. What you posted does contain a syntax error (the trailing `.`) and has other issues but nothing that would produce an error message like you're saying it does. And if you do get an error message, post the actual error message not something `like` it.

Comment: The line of code you show just hangs reading stdin because you have not provided any input file for the first awk.   You should probably echo the filename into the first awk, and I imagine you mean `$1` rather than `$f`.  But none of that produces the syntax error you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do this in Bash alone.

Given:

```
$ st="ABC_20100702001500.CSV"
```

You can use parameter expansion to remove the front and back portion:

```
$ tmp="${st#*_}"
$ echo "${tmp%.*}"
20100702001500
```

Or, Bash has regex capability as well:

```
$ [[ $st =~ ^[^_]*_([^.]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
20100702001500
```

Or, use `sed` if you have an older non Bash shell:

```
$ echo "$st" | sed -E 's/^[^_]*_//; s/\..*$//'
20100702001500
```

Comment: While good advice, the code the OP posted cannot produce the error message she says it does so trying to fix or improve that code will only go so far towards helping with whatever problem she really has.

Comment: @EdMorton: Agreed. Until clarified, I thought tips on getting started might help.